# Two Dimensional Array Constraints: Sudoku

Tags: java, constraints, constraint-programming

I am attempting to solve Sudoku as a constraint satisfaction problem for a homework assignment.  I have already constructed constraints for all the elements in a particular row being distinct, as well as for columns.  I am trying to construct the constraints for the elements in a sub-region being distinct, and I'm running into some trouble.

The general idea behind my current algorithm is to add all of the variables that are in a sub-region (e.g. a 3x3 box for a 9x9 grid) into a list, and then permute all the values in that list to construct NotEqualConstraints between each variable.  The code below works properly for the 1st subregion of a NxN grid, but I am not sure how I should change this to iterate through the rest of the entire grid.

```
int incSize = (int)Math.sqrt(svars.length);

ArrayList<Variable> subBox = new ArrayList<Variable>();

for (int ind = 0; ind < incSize; ind++) {
for (int ind2 = 0; ind2 < incSize; ind2++) {
    subBox.add(svars[ind][ind2]);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < subBox.size(); i++) {
for (int j = i + 1; j < subBox.size(); j++) {
   NotEqualConstraint row = new NotEqualConstraint(subBox.get(i), subBox.get(j));
   constraints.add(row);
   }
}
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction about how I can modify the code to hit each subregion and not just the top left one?

**edit: I am also open to trying any algorithm that works, it is not necessary to add all of the values to an ArrayList for each sub-region. If you see a better way, please share insight**

Comment: Arr, what be ye question, me lad?

Comment: The given code iterates through the first subregion start at the top left of the grid, but not each subregion of the grid.

Comment: It's just simple arithmetic, nothing more. If you worked it out on paper, you'd see the algorithm immediately.

Comment: I've been working it out on paper for a while, not quite so easy for me :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working solution I came up with, for those interested:

```
for (int ofs = 0; ofs < svars.length; ofs++) {
    int col = (ofs % incSize) * incSize;
    int row = ((int)(ofs / incSize)) * incSize;

    ArrayList<Variable> subBox = new ArrayList<Variable>();
    for (int ind = row; ind < row+incSize; ind++) {
        for (int ind2 = col; ind2 < col+incSize; ind2++) {
            subBox.add(svars[ind][ind2]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < subBox.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < subBox.size(); j++) {
               NotEqualConstraint c = new NotEqualConstraint(subBox.get(i), subBox.get(j));
               constraints.add(c);
            }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to do, but the below algorithm should give you every value you need. You can just ignore and/or remove the values you don't need. You could probably fill all your arrays appropriately at the point where you have all the numbers.

The words I use:

- square: a single square to put a number in.
- subregion: a group of squares, a 3x3 grid in the classic sudoku.
- puzzle: the whole thing, 3x3 subregions and 9x9 squares.

Code:

```
//You should have these values at this point:
int subRegionWidth = something; //amount of horizontal squares in a subregion
int subRegionHeight = something; //amount of vertical squares in a subregion
int amountOfHorizontalSubRegions = something; //amount of subRegion columns next to each other
int amountOfVerticalSubRegions = something; //amount of subregion rows on top of each other

//Doesn't change, so calculated once in advance:
int squaresPerPuzzleRow = subRegionWidth*amountOfHorizontalSubRegions;

//Variables to use inside the loop:
int subRegionIndex = 0;
int squareColumnInPuzzle;
int squareRowInPuzzle;
int squareIndexInPuzzle;
int squareIndexInSubRegion;

for(int subRegionRow=0; subRegionRow<amountOfVerticalSubRegions;subRegionRow++)
{
    for(int subRegionColumn=0; subRegionColumn<amountOfHorizontalSubRegions;subRegionColumn++)
    {
        for(int squareRowInRegion=0; squareRowInRegion<subRegionHeight; squareRowInRegion++)
        {
            for(int squareColumnInRegion=0; squareColumnInRegion<subRegionWidth; squareColumnInRegion++)
            {
                squareColumnInPuzzle = subRegionColumn*subRegionWidth + squareColumnInRegion;
                squareRowInPuzzle = subRegionRow*subRegionHeight + squareRowInRegion;
                squareIndexInPuzzle = squareRowInPuzzle*squaresPerPuzzleRow + squareColumnInPuzzle;
                squareIndexInSubRegion = squareRowInRegion*subRegionWidth + squareColumnInRegion;

                //You now have all the information of a square:

                //The subregion's row (subRegionRow)
                //The subregion's column (subRegionColumn)
                //The subregion's index (subRegionIndex)
                //The square's row within the puzzle (squareRowInPuzzle)
                //The square's column within the puzzle (squareColumnInPuzzle)
                //The square's index within the puzzle (squareIndexInPuzzle)
                //The square's row within the subregion (squareRowInSubRegion)
                //The square's column within the subregion (squareColumnInSubRegion)
                //The square's index within the subregion (squareIndexInSubRegion)

                //You'll get this once for all squares, add the code to do something with it here.
            }
        }
        subRegionIndex++;
    }
}
```

If you only need the top left squares per subregion, just remove the inner two loops:

```
for(int subRegionRow=0; subRegionRow<amountOfVerticalSubRegions;subRegionRow++)
{
    for(int subRegionColumn=0; subRegionColumn<amountOfHorizontalSubRegions;subRegionColumn++)
    {
        squareColumnInPuzzle = subRegionColumn*subRegionWidth;
        squareRowInPuzzle = subRegionRow*subRegionHeight;
        squareIndexInPuzzle = squareRowInPuzzle*squaresPerPuzzleRow + squareColumnInPuzzle;

        //You now have all the information of a top left square:

        //The subregion's row (subRegionRow)
        //The subregion's column (subRegionColumn)
        //The subregion's index (subRegionIndex)
        //The square's row within the puzzle (squareRowInPuzzle)
        //The square's column within the puzzle (squareColumnInPuzzle)
        //The square's index within the puzzle (squareIndexInPuzzle)
        //The square's row within the subregion (always 0)
        //The square's column within the subregion (always 0)
        //The square's index within the subregion (always 0)

        //You'll get this once for all squares, add the code to do something with it here.

        subRegionIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int start1 = start1; start1 < svars.length/incSize; start1 ++) {
    for (int start2 = start2; start2 < svars.length/incSize; start2++) {//iterate through all subsets
        ArrayList<Variable> subBox = new ArrayList<Variable>();

        for (int ind = start1*incSize; ind < incSize; ind++) {
            for (int ind2 = start2*incSize; ind2 < incSize; ind2++) {
                 subBox.add(svars[ind][ind2]);
            }
        }

       for (int i = 0; i < subBox.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < subBox.size(); j++) {
           NotEqualConstraint row = new NotEqualConstraint(subBox.get(i), subBox.get(j));
           constraints.add(row);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can not compile the above code snippet. for some strange reason you are initializing start1 to itself without ever initializing start1. Same can be said of start2.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm not sure your algorithm is correct, however, as I tested it and does not recognize when every subregion besides the first has duplicate numbers.  Note, I did change start1 and start2 to be initialized to 0.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't completely understand what you are trying to do but if you are trying to solve the puzzle you just need a recursive method that will put in numbers until it fills all the grid and puzzle is valid.That was my solution for a futoshiki puzzle solver( similar to sudoku)

Comment: I am solving the puzzle as a constraint satisfaction problem.  I have an algorithm to solve the puzzle once the constraints are established (the step I am stuck on), that is more efficient than brute force.

Comment: Downvote as post states explicitly as CSP problem. The obvious solution is recursion, as CSP will require 27*9! about 6 million different constraints...

Comment: How do you reason that number?  The number of constraints for 9x9 should be 810, 4x4 should be 56.